# Routing for trucks with restrictions is not respected

Tags: api, testing, routes, here-api

we started testing the Routing API in our system and there were some questions:
our goal is to calculate a route for a large truck, to determine whether it will be able to get to the delivery point, taking into account its dimensions and weight. We have formed a request according to the instructions. The request deliberately indicated the delivery point to which the truck would not be able to reach. We expected the route calculation to fail, but it did. We made other attempts with different addresses and got the same result - the route is calculated for the streets that are not passable. We did not find any information describing this behavior in the documentation. Tell me how we can achieve the desired result so that the route is not calculated if the street is not passable for a truck on the last mile?
An example of the request we tested:

router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=truck&truck[grossWeight]=20000&truck[height]=300&truck[width]=245&truck[length]=1300&origin=44.65842,10.77567&destination=38.550680,15.938761&return=summary&apiKey=

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. In particular, it is _vital_ to provide relevant tags or at least mention the software you are using. I have added the [tag:here-api] tag as a guess based on the domain in your question, but I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about. "The Routing API" is far from specific.